# How to set equal width between ticks - chartjs

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a chart which now looks like this:

[image]

```
    xAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'log(Re)',
      },
      type: 'linear',
      ticks: {
        suggestedMax: 10000,
        maxTicksLimit: 10,
      },

      afterBuildTicks: function(scale) {
        scale.ticks = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
      }
    }]
```

Need to create ticks [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000], (like in first image), but with equal spacing between this ticks, like here: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dmytro, I think your basic problem is that the tick marks you want are powers of 10, not plain numbers. Set your tick marks to be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and they will be shown at even intervals. Then label them 1, 10, 100, etc. (1=10^0, 10=10^1, 100=10^2, etc). You may have to restructure your data set a bit to get the correct tick mark values in. But that should give you the effect you are after.